# SVG Browser Bug - wp_remote_get()

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, svg, safari

I'm working on a WordPress site and have an array of "icon blocks" that contains a selector for an **svg**, and a few other details I need for each icon block. In my template file I'm looping over these blocks and using `wp_remote_get()` to pull the contents of the selected **svg** file and insert it into my page's html.

Although I'm pulling back the contents of three unique files the first file is being displayed 3 times, here is a screenshot (This is in Chrome):

[image: screenshot]

However, if I open the same page in Safari I get the same repeating icons, but with a different icon. Here is the Safari screenshot:

[image: screenshot2]

If you run a dif on the svg's on the page, they are indeed different svgs.

Any help would be appreciated. [Here](http://kb2.projects.cgd.io/innovation-readiness/strategy/) is a link to the staging site if you want to look at it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use unique ids - the three SVG snippets repeat some. The lines

```
<clipPath id="clip-path">
```

and

```
<g style="clip-path:url(#clip-path)">
```

After importing they are all part of the same document, and references fail.

Comment: That did it! Thanks... I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Crazy. Good find.